# Coaxial cable and faraday cage: why those shielding properties precisely?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, conductors

The magnetic field produced by a coaxial cable outside of the outer shell is $0$. Indeed, integrating $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=\mu_0 \mathbf{j}$ along a circle outside the outer shell, the inner conductor current and outside conductor current give contribution that exactly compensate.

I have read that one of its advantage is to provide a shielding. It doesn't generate any E.M field outside, and an outside E.M field will not perturb its signal.

About the fact it doesn't generate outside E.M signal, I totally agree with the fact the magnetic field produced outside will be $0$ because of the given explanation. About the electric field I guess it is also $0$ because, first, there are no static charges. And next, as $\mathbf{B}=0$ outside of the conductor, then the magnetic field cannot induce from Maxwell equation an electric field.

### My questions are the following:

The derivation made to prove no magnetic field is produced outside assumes that the ingoing current in the inner conductor is exactly the opposite as the outgoing current of the outer shield. But is it still true in the context of wave propagation ? If I assume I send a current pulse on the outer shield, will it be exactly instantaneously compensated by an opposite current on the outer shield ? For me the current wave must propagate until the end of the line, then bounces back, and goes back on the inner line. And, after I waited long enough I will indeed have inner current = - outer current. Thus in a regime of varying signals I won't have in principle a zero magnetic field outside.

Am I correct ? Am I making a mistake ?

The second question I have is: why an outside E.M field cannot enter inside ? Is the answer based on the fact the outer surface is metallic and totally reflects any outside E.M wave ?

What disturbs me is that this fact is true for any metallic wire (thus not only coaxial cable): electric field will never enter in it. The thing we should protect against is outside magnetic field that would induce current. And this is a property of the geometry of the full circuit not of the wire in itself (if my circuit has a square shape, magnetic flux inside of this square can induce currents).

I am not understanding this point either then